# Deactivating commandButton functionality if inputText validation fails or ajax call starts

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following piece of code inside a form:

```
<p:panel id="panel" header="lalalala">
    <h:panelGrid columns="5">

        <h:outputLabel value="Enter name" for="name" />

        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{userBean.name}"
            required="true" label="name" maxlength="15"
            validatorMessage="oops"
            requiredMessage="ooopps">
            <f:validateRegex
                pattern="^somepattern$">
            </f:validateRegex>
            <p:ajax event="blur" update="inputValidationMessage" />
        </p:inputText>

        <p:message id="inputValidationMessage" showSummary="false"
            for="name" />
        <p:watermark for="name" value="eg. John" />

    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" update="panel"
        actionListener="#{userBean.save}"
        onclick="handleOnclick"
        oncomplete="handleAjaxResponse(xhr, status, args)">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" />
</p:panel>
```

So the validation messages work well on the `inputText` element. But the submit button is still making an Ajax request when clicked, even though the input is invalid. I want the Ajax request to be sent iff the inputText is valid.

How do I do that?

Furthermore; there is another case I'd like to deactivate the button. This is the case where inputText is validated and the user clicks the button. The reason for this one is, I don't want the user to mistakenly flood requests. (i.e repeatedly press the submit button)

Currently, the `handleOnclick` javascript function only shows a modal dialog box saying "wait". Since that dialog is modal, the background is inaccessible. However, that still doesn't prevent the user from pressing it repeatedly because 1 second passes between onclick and modal dialog showing. Furthermore; this approach doesn't prevent submitting invalid data. What can you suggest?

I use JSF2.0 and Primefaces 3.0.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the button's `disabled` attribute for it. Just set it to `true` whenever [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) returns `false` (so, it's an initial request), or when it's `true` (so, a form submit has occurred), then check if [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) returns `true` (so the validation has failed in general).

```html
<p:commandButton ... disabled="#{not facesContext.postback or facesContext.validationFailed}" />
```

You only need to ensure that you update the button on ajax requests as well, so that it will reappear either enabled or disabled when necessary.

```html
<p:ajax event="blur" update="inputValidationMessage submitButton" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer BalusC. What you proposed is functioning but with bad user experience. When I load the page and enter some valid text into the inputText, the commandButton don't get enabled immediately. Since it's disabled initially on page load, after entering something valid, I have to click somewhere else on the page so that the blur event triggers and the buttons becomes enabled. Only then I can click the button. However, this may cause bad user experience. How can I deal with that?

Comment: So there's a single input field? I understood that you have multiple input fields which needs to be validated. You can just remove the `#{facesContext.postback}` check then.

Comment: So I've only got `disabled="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"` now. That solves the problem I mentioned but the same thing happens when validation fails. I load the page, enter something invalid, button gets disabled. Then I enter something valid but have to click somewhere else to enable the button again. Only then I can click the button. What would you suggest to prevent bad user experience in such a scenario?

Comment: You could use `keyup` instead of `blur`, but that'll result in more ajax requests. Alternatively, just don't disable the button at all :)

Comment: Can I tell JSF to do those validations on client-side? Why does it Ajax anyway? :) I'm afraid if the button is not disabled on invalid input, user can submit invalid requests. I don't want the button to work or submit anything if input is invalid.

Comment: No, JSF doesn't support client side validation. Client side validation is spoofable/hackable while server side validation is robust. User can submit invalid requests, but they will not be processed (i.e. button's action method will not be invoked). That's regardless of whether you use ajax or not.

Comment: Alright, so I removed the `disabled` attribute. One last thing; the onclick of the button calls a Javascript function which shows a modal dialog box. Since disabled is removed, the dialog shows anyway. How can I tell it to popup iff validation succeeds? I could call that function on `onstart` instead of `onclick` but `onstart` takes a bit of time to execute. So 2 seconds pass from the click and the dialog showing, which feels unresponsive.

Comment: Use `visible="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}"` and ajax-update it instead. 2 seconds is pretty a lot though, isn't it just your business logic / DB performance / hardware which is inefficient?

Comment: Not really, all operations I perform are `O(1)`. It runs on localhost and there is no DB :) Perhaps it's my laptop or something

Comment: @ihebiheb: Not sure what you're talking about. That's already covered by the answer.