# How to prevent/stop submit of commandbutton when having on going AJAX-call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form with a few different text fields which the user needs to fill in to be able to go to the next step. The next step of the page is accessed by clicking a commandbutton "Next" and should only be enabled when all of the fields are valid (validated on the server).

The problem is that the user can click the "next step" button directly after changing a field with valid input to invalid input, without loosing focus on the field, causing the validation to not get triggered in time to prevent the user to go to the next step.

Here is an example of one of the fields, together with the commandbutton doing the submit.

```
<p:inputTextarea id="lineFreeText" value="#{line.freeText}" rows="1" disabled="#{facesContext.validationFailed and component.valid}"
    maxlength="#{itemConstant.MAX_FREE_TEXT_LENGTH}" counter="freeTextCounter"
    counterTemplate="{0}/#{itemConstant.MAX_FREE_TEXT_LENGTH}" rendered="#{showFreeText and !line.hasItemForm()}" validator="freeTextValidator" validatorMessage="#{messages.freeTextRequired}" requiredMessage="#{messages.freeTextRequired}">
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{cartController.saveLine(line)}" update="@form cartForm lineFreeText lineEditedSymbols lineFreeTextMessage @([id$=nextStepBtn])" />
</p:inputTextarea>

     <h:commandButton value="#{messages['checkout.nextStep']}" id="nextStepBtn"  rendered="#{cartController.size() gt 0 and !clientContext.OCIRequest}"
        onclick="$('.jqRealNextStepButton').click();" style="border: 2px solid #008091; padding: 0.5em;"
        styleClass="ju-button" disabled="#{clientContext.client.visitor or checkoutDeliveryDateController.disableNextButton() or totalMinAmountNotMet or facesContext.validationFailed or not facesContext.postback}"
        title="#{clientContext.client.visitor ? messages.disabledForVisitor : tooltip}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" />
    </h:commandButton>
```

I want the commandbutton to cancel the submit when there's an on going ajax happening, so that the validation can finish before the form is submitted, enabling me to prevent users from inputting invalid data and continuing. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Cheers

Comment: Review this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886850/deactivating-commandbutton-functionality-if-inputtext-validation-fails-or-ajax-c?rq=1

Comment: Use `<p:commandButton>` or `<p:ajax>` instead and retry. Ajax requests within context of same framework are by default queued. You're right now using the one from PrimeFaces for input and the one from standard JSF for submit. They are by default not aware of each other.

Comment: @BalusC I've tried changing both the commandbutton and the ajax-event to the primefaces equivalent, but still no luck. Any other ideas? Could it be related to the fact that the commandbutton currently calls click() onclick on a commandlink, that calls the underlying controller, proceeding to the next step? When I inspect in devtools I can clearly see the inputfield ajax change event being processed first.

Comment: Update: I tried removing the step that causes the button to call click on the commandlink, and simply placed the action-method on the commandbutton and *voila* - worked straight away liked you said it would. I blame the ex-developer on the team who implemented this ;-) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the commandbutton to the primefaces one, and remove the `onclick` pointing to another commandlink, which executed the backend-logic to traverse to the next page. When I put the action-method in the `<p:commandbutton/>` the ajax-events were properly queued.